# Why does my recursive function not stop even if it reaches the return (0)?

Tags: c, dictionary

I've made a recursive function which browses a list and tries to put the pieces of the list in a map. I have a function which checks if they fit on the map.

However if the map is too small the recursion should stop and return (0), but it doesn't. I put a `printf("DONE")` just before the return and the terminal print it but the function still running. How is this possible? [DONE is printed several time even if return (0) is below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58PN3.png)

```
int fillit_algo (t_fill *orilst, t_map *map) {

    int     i;
    int     j;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    if (orilst == NULL)
        return (1);

    while (map->map[i] != 0)
    {
        while (map->map[i][j])
        {
            if (fill_map(map, orilst, i, j))
            {
                if((fillit_algo(orilst->next, map)))
                    return (1);
            }
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
    printf ("DONE\n");

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Because you call the function multiple times? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Each recursive call is essentially a nested function call. When you reach `return (0);` code execution picks up in the previous call to `fillit_algo` and that "unwinding" continues until you `return (0);` from the original function call.

Comment: Using `for()` loops instead of `while()` would simplify this function.

Comment: A recursion can be seen as a tree, where some branches reach the "DONE" before others do.

Comment: I need to stop my function when it reach the return (0). I call this function only one time. But I don't want to pick the previous call, how can I do ?

Comment: It's written in such a way that it's not done when reaching return(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if((fillit_algo(orilst->next, map)))
    return (1);
```

If fillit_algo return 0 after it gets called, then it is possible to print multiple "DONE" statements. So handle 'return 0'  case in your code.

Example:

```
 if((fillit_algo(orilst->next, map)))
        return (1);
  else 
       return 0;
```

Comment: Could be shorter written as `return fillit_algo(orilst->next, map);`.

Answer (score 1):

Oh well...

It was so simple, thank you a lot I didn't mind this thing.
I've just put a "else return (0)" and it's fix !

```
int     fillit_algo(t_fill *orilst, t_map *map){
int     i;
int     j;

i = 0;
j = 0;
if (orilst == NULL)
    return (1);
while (map->map[i] != 0)
{
    while (map->map[i][j])
    {
        if (fill_map(map, orilst, i, j))
        {
            if((fillit_algo(orilst->next, map)))
                return (1);
            else
                return (0);
        }
        j++;
    }
    j = 0;
    i++;
}
printf ("DONE");
return (0);}
```

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). In short: Don't take what the answer told you and then rewrite it in your own answer.